# Extracting Web Elements using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a web crawler with a custom extraction feature, so it can crawl web pages and extract data from different page elements on each page. On every page on my website, I have:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'eventName'});
```

The goal is to create a regex where it extracts eventName from every occurrence of that string in the page.

I tried creating the following regex:

```
dataLayer.push["({'event': '].*["'});]
```

but the problem is that it returns anything on the page after the semicolon. How can I end the regular expression at the semicolon and just get it to extract `dataLayer.push({'event': 'eventName'});` on each page?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of web crawler's extraction feature]

Comment: Show multiple sample inputs and matching required outputs

Comment: Your regex doesn't do what you (probably) think it does, `[...]` is not a grouping construct, it's a set of possible matches (single characters)

Comment: When I replace .* with [\s\S]*? it only returns dataLayer.push({'

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that my regex is not written correctly. I'm looking for some help to get it corrected. I'm in the marketing department and do not have much experience with regular expressions.

Comment: I repeat: **Show multiple sample inputs and matching required outputs**.

Comment: `dataLayer.push({'event': 'facebookConversion'});`
`dataLayer.push({'event': 'googleConversion'});`
`dataLayer.push({'event': 'remarketing'});`

I am looking to extract the event names, such as facebookConversion, googleConversion, and remarketing.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xI9jL9/1)? Or [like this](https://regex101.com/r/xI9jL9/2)? Note that these regexes have a capturing group, the contents you need is in Group 1.

Comment: Either one is fine. If I had to choose I would choose the first one with only `'event': 'eventName'`

Comment: Although it looks like it is only pulling one of the eventNames out of the page, how do I get it to pull all?